# Lua - trying to create a good Vec2 class

Tags: oop, lua, love2d, metatable, meta-method

I'm learning how to use Lua and Love2d and I want to create a Vec2 class using metamethods and metatables. This is what I have so far:

class.lua: (The base class files)

```
local Class = {}
Class.__index = Class

-- Constructor
function Class:new() end

-- Inherite from Class
-- type = The name of the new class
function Class:derive(type)
  print("Class:", self)
  local cls = {}
  cls["__call"] = Class.__call
  cls.type = type
  cls.__index = cls
  cls.super = self
  setmetatable(cls, self)
  return cls
end

function Class:__call(...)
  local inst = setmetatable({}, self)
  inst:new(...)
  return inst
end

function Class:getType()
  return self.type
end

return Class
```

vec2.lua

```
local class = require "class"
local Vec2 = class:derive("Vec2")

function Vec2:new(x, y)
  self.x = x or 0
  self.y = y or 0
  getmetatable(self).__add = Vec2.add
end

function Vec2.add(a, b)
  local nx, ny
  nx = a.x + b.x
  ny = a.y + b.y
  return Vec2:new(nx, ny)
end

return Vec2
```

and in my main.lua I have:

```
local v1 = Vec2:new(10, 10)
local v2 = Vec2:new(5, 3)
local v3 = v1 + v2
print("v3:", v3.x, v3.y)
```

and I get this error:

> Error: main.lua:12: attempt to perform arithmetic on local 'v1' (a nil
>   value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vec2.new` does not return a value. Hence the assignment `local v1 = Vec2:new(10,10)` results in `v1` being `nil`

Try `local v1 = Vec2(10,10)` instead. Same mistake in `Vec2.add`

The instance is created in the `__call` metamethod which calls new with your parameters. You're not supposed to call `new` directly unless you want to re-initialize an existing instance.

```
function Class:__call(...)
  local inst = setmetatable({}, self)
  inst:new(...)
  return inst
end
```

Comment: Now if I want to add another class with a different add metamethod, how do I do it without interrupting Vec2.add?

Comment: @roydbt please post a new question.